# Is it possible to use a range slider without numerical values but to reveal content instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css, range

I'm trying to create a range slider that will have 4 different points across it (with labels), so that when you click and drag the picker to a specific point on the slider, it will reveal content below that will correspond to that point on the slider. So, in a way it would work as a regular slider, only instead of navigation arrows/bullets it would use a range slider to switch between slides. Is this something that's at all possible?

I would have used a regular slider in this case, but the whole idea is to click and drag the bullet that will scroll across, so I can't think of any other way of implementing it.

Comment: You should probably add some things that you have tried to get better answers.. That said I am guessing you are looking at something like [this](http://www.shibajidebnath.com/create-custom-slider-with-javascript-function/)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. (You should be a bit more specific if that's not the answer you are looking for.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign each point a value and use an if statement that will check the value of the selected point and update the content when the slider moves to another point.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like a great solution :)

Comment: You Are Welcome! You are the first person that I answer and give a correct solution to.